# Thread waiting another thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I need an explanation here.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    FirstThread obj = new FirstThread();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      new WaiterThread(obj).start();
    }
    obj.start();
  }

public class FirstThread extends Thread {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Do something
  }
}


public class WaiterThread extends Thread {
  Object obj;

  WaiterThread(Object obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    synchronized (obj) {
           obj.wait();
    }
  }
}
```

10 threads are created for *WaiterThread* and are waiting for a single *FirstThread* object. After *FirstThread* terminates, all *WaiterThread* s resumed without *obj.notify()* or *obj.notifyAll()* being called anywhere.

Does that mean  *WaiterThread* s stopped waiting for *FirstThread* because it gets terminated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [the documentation of the `Thread` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29), a dying thread calls `notifyAll` on the instance which represents it.

Furthermore, quoting the same documentation:

> It is recommended that applications not use `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` on `Thread` instances.

Of course, the same recommendation applies to instances of `Thread` *subclasses*, which is what your code is doing.

Answer (score 6):

This is a side-effect of the fact that when a thread terminates, it invokes this.notifyAll() (as documented in the javadoc of [`Thread.join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29)). The same javadoc also makes the following recommendation:

> It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances

Comment: People will suspect that we are sitting in the same room :)

Comment: It would be a pleasure to meet you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I modified a code a bit as below

main() method remains the same

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    FirstThread obj = new FirstThread();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      new WaiterThread(obj).start();
    }
    obj.start();
  }
```

change is as follows

```
class WaiterThread extends Thread {
    Object obj;

    WaiterThread(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (obj) {
            try {
                obj.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Thread " + this.getId() + "started");
        }
        System.out.println("Out of sync block by " + this.getId());
    }
}
```

ant the output I got is

```
FirstThread Started
Thread 19started
Out of sync block by 19
Thread 18started
Out of sync block by 18
Thread 17started
Out of sync block by 17
Thread 16started
Out of sync block by 16
Thread 15started
Out of sync block by 15
Thread 14started
Out of sync block by 14
Thread 13started
Out of sync block by 13
Thread 12started
Out of sync block by 12
Thread 11started
Out of sync block by 11
Thread 10started
Out of sync block by 10
```

So you have your answer. They are not started simultaneously! FirstThread calls notifyAll() while dying out which notifies all but each thread can have the lock only one at a time. So though every thread is notified only one thread executes at a time.